Atomic species flag for deuterium is replaced by Phonopy in Quantum ESPRESSO inputs
I am running some Phonopy calculations with a deuterated material. I already know that Quantum ESPRESSO does not understand D at atomic species, but instead we need an H2 flag such as follows:
ATOMIC_SPECIES
   I  126.90400   I.upf
   H    1.00750   H.upf
   N   14.00650   N.upf
  H2    2.01410   H.upf
  Pb  207.20000  Pb.upf
   C   12.01060   C.upf

The problem is, when I run Phonopy to create the supercells, Phonopy replaces this H2 flag by an O in all the supercells for the scf calculation:
ATOMIC_SPECIES
 Pb  207.20000   Pb.upf
  I  126.90400   I.upf
  N   14.00650   N.upf
  C   12.01060   C.upf
  O    2.01410   H.upf
  H    1.00750   H.upf


This is a problem, since I want to extract a theoretical Inelastic Neutron Scattering spectra from the output, and for this matter oxygen is quite different from my beloved deuterium.
Any idea of how to tackle this? Thanks in advance.

I would suggest looking at the phonopy source code and modifying if you have to. It shouldnt be hard... anyway, if you want to calculate neutron scattering spectra from phonopy, take a look at euphonic! https://euphonic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Thanks for the suggestion! I am playing with AbINS for now, will check euphonic later, thanks!

@TylerSterling I checked Phonopy's source code, and it does in fact implement isotopes, in phonopy/structures/atoms.py. However, I do not see how could this be translated to reading the proper H2 value. For now, I have opened a github issue (https://github.com/phonopy/phonopy/issues/412)

I wasn't aware of that code! Neat. Cheers!
